# Open multiple keep-alives to a server in Go

Tags: go

I have an application that opens a keep-alive to a few remote servers (that I control). It sends a heart beat packet to keep this connection alive before the timeout.

This is how I created my transport:

```
// Keep-alive connection to the servers
tr := &http.Transport{}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

If I use `&http.Transport{MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 2}` and set it to > 2, then I'm able to maintain multiple keep-alives per remote connection. However, these additional keep-alives per remote server are created by Go itself when there are concurrent requests that have to be made, and terminated automatically after the timeout expires.

My question is: how can I create the additional keep-alives, say 5 keep-alives per remote server myself when I initialize my transport (when I start Go) and keep them all alive? This would speed up subsequent requests greatly and speed is very important.

Comment: it doesn't look like Transport times out idle connections, something else needs to close them.

Comment: You're right, it respects the keep-alive timeout duration of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on inputs from the go-nuts group, to manually open multiple keep-alives to one server, we make that many *simultaneous requests*. Go then keeps these alive till the remote server times them out (default 5 seconds in Apache).

Please note that these connections cannot be more than the `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` which is 2 by default.

You can verify this behaviour using `netstat -p tcp`